# Selecting an element of an array without specifying an array in awk

Tags: arrays, awk

I'd like to select a specific element of an array from a file with awk where the file is not setup specifying every entry as being part of an array. I plan on putting this in a for loop or assigning this as a variable to be used for arithmetic opterations. However, I am finding that I cannot use the way I'm selecting the element of the array when assigning it as a variable or using it in a for loop.

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9  8  7  6
```

If these elements are not specified in awk as being part of an array, referencing them could be done with

```
FNR == 1 {print $3}
```

However, I cannot assign this as a variable to be used later, nor can I put this in a loop.
Is there another way to reference a single element of an array without having to restructure the input file?

Comment: I don't get your question.... :(

Comment: This is probably an X-Y question.  It's better to ask what you're trying to do instead of a workaround for a step.  Of course you can assign variables in `awk`, but perhaps it's not what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file into an array, then access the array. When accessing the array, use `split`:

```
{ array[NR] = $0 }
```

After the input scanning is complete, `array[42]` gives you the contents of record #42, usually the 42nd line of the input. We can put in an `END { ... }` block where we process the array.

To get the third element of `array[1]`, we can do this:

```
split(array[1], fields)
```

Now we have an array called `fields`. `fields[3]` holds the same datum as `$3` held when the first record were being processed which we assigned to `array[1]`.

In Awk we can also simulate two-dimensional arrays, by catenating multiple indices together with some unambiguous separator, like a space or dash.

```
{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
    array[NR "-" i] = $i }
```

After this executes for every input record, we can access `$3` from record 1 as `array["1-3"]`.  The key `1-3` is a character string.

The expression `NR "-" i` in the loop body places several expressions next to each other with no operators in between. That denotes string catenation. When `NR` is 17 and `i` is 5, we get the string `"17-5"` and so on.

Since the number of fields per record is variable, we could have another array which gives the `NF` value for each element of `array`.

```
{ nf[i] = NF;
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
    array[NR "-" i] = $i }
```

Now we know that if `nf[17]` is 5, the fields `array["17-1"]` through `array["17-5"]` are valid.